# Java Networking Server not Responding to Client

Tags: java, networking

I am attempting to build a networked version of Battleship, and am running into an issue where it seems that my server either isn't receiving the client's request or the server is having trouble sending the response back to the client. What I do know is that my server executes a new thread upon accept(), but unfortunately I have no idea what is going wrong beyond that point. I am having trouble finding a way to debug the new thread using eclipse. Below is the code I currently have for my three classes. Assume the client enters 1 to make a request to see a list of available games. Client just hangs while waiting for the response. Server should hit case "list". Any help on where I've gone wrong would be wonderful.

```
public class Server {
    //global variables for clients to call whenever
    public static ArrayList<Socket> ClientArray = new ArrayList<Socket>();
    public static ArrayList<String> ClientNameArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<Socket> WaitingClients = new ArrayList<Socket>();
    public static ArrayList<String> WaitingPlaterNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {

            final int PORT = 7334;
            ServerSocket SERVER = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            System.out.println("waiting on client connections");

            //infinite accept
            while(true){
                Socket sock = SERVER.accept();
                ClientArray.add(sock);
                System.out.println("Client added");
                addName(sock);

                ServerGame serverSide = new ServerGame(sock);
                serverSide.start();
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void addName(Socket sock){
        try {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
            String user = input.readLine();
            ClientNameArray.add(user);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Then ServerGame:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerGame extends Thread {
    private Socket sock;
    private BufferedReader input = null;
    private PrintWriter out = null;
    String commandMessage = "";

    public ServerGame(Socket sock) {
        this.sock = sock;
    }

    private void checkConnection() {
        if (!sock.isConnected()) {
            //if not connected anymore remove from client list
            for (int i = 0; i < Server.ClientArray.size(); i++) {
                if (Server.ClientArray.get(i) == sock) {
                    Server.ClientArray.remove(i);
                    Server.ClientNameArray.remove(i);
                }
            }
            //check if client started new game and is waiting. If so
            //remove them from that list too
            for(int j = 0; j < Server.WaitingClients.size(); j++){
                if(Server.WaitingClients.get(j) == sock){
                    Server.WaitingClients.remove(j);
                    Server.WaitingPlaterNames.remove(j);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void parseAndSend(String commandMessage) {
        boolean found = false;
        String[] message = commandMessage.split("\\s+");
        // 3rd argument in message is always the command
        switch (message[2]) {

        // initial inquiry cases
        case "list":
            String inquiry;
            if(Server.WaitingPlaterNames.size() != 0){
                inquiry = "Available Games: " + Server.WaitingPlaterNames;
            }
            else{
                inquiry = "No Available Games";
            }
            try {
                out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
                out.println(inquiry);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        case "newgame":
            break;
        case "join":
            break;

        // game commands
        case "connection":
            // make output to other player's socket
            for (int i = 0; i < Server.ClientArray.size(); i++) {
                if (Server.ClientNameArray.get(i).equals(message[1])) {
                    try {
                        // set outputstream to other player's socket
                        out = new PrintWriter(Server.ClientArray.get(i)
                                .getOutputStream());
                        found = true;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if you didn't find the player send back to sender fail
            if (!found) {
                try {
                    out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
                    String failMessage = "attempt connection failure";
                    out.println(failMessage);
                    return;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            // is this a request or confirmation?
            if (message[3].equals("request")) {
                String sendMessage = message[0] + " " + message[1]
                        + " connection request";
                // send it to opponent's socket
                out.println(sendMessage);
                return;
            } else { // finalization from other side to server
                String sendMessage = message[0] + " " + message[1]
                        + " connection finalized";
                out.println(sendMessage);
                return;
            }
        case "move":
            break;
        case "chat":
            break;
        case "failure":
            break;
        default:
            return;

        }
        out.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
            commandMessage = input.readLine();
            System.out.println("Command Message Received : " + commandMessage);
            while (!commandMessage.equals("DISCONNECT")) {
                checkConnection();

                parseAndSend(commandMessage);
                commandMessage = input.readLine();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            try {
                System.out.println("Closing Connection...");
                if (null != input) {
                    input.close();
                }
                if (null != out) {
                    out.close();
                }
                if (null != sock) {
                    sock.close();
                    System.out.println("Socket Closed.");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and Finally my Client:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;


public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        InetAddress address = null;
        Socket socket = null;
        String commandMessage = "";
        String myUsrname = "";
        String opponentName = "";
        BufferedReader input = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader myInput = null;
        final int PORT = 7334;
        try {
            //get my address for socket
            address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Welcome to BattleCarrier! (BattleShip was taken)");
        System.out.println("************************************************");
        System.out.println("************************************************");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("To Register, please type in a Username.");

        myInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String consoleCommand = "";
        while(consoleCommand.equals("")){
            try {
                consoleCommand = myInput.readLine();

                if(consoleCommand.equals("")){
                    System.out.println("How about a real username???");
                    continue;
                }

                myUsrname = consoleCommand;
                System.out.println("Your Username has been set to " + myUsrname + ".");
                System.out.println("Setting up a connection with the server...");

                //set up the socket
                if(null != address){
                    socket = new Socket(address, PORT);
                    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

                    System.out.println("Client Address: " + address);
                    System.out.println("Connection Established with Server");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Server may not be reachable. Please Try again later.");
                System.out.println("Goodbye.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Please choose from the following commands:");
        System.out.println("*********************************************************");
        System.out.println("Type: 1 for available games.");
        System.out.println("Type: 2 to start a new game.");
        System.out.println("Type: 3 to join someone else.");
        System.out.println("*********************************************************");
        System.out.println("Type: \"DISCONNECT\" at any time to unregister and quit.");
        System.out.println("*********************************************************");

        try {
            consoleCommand = myInput.readLine();
            while(!consoleCommand.equals("DISCONNECT")){
                switch(consoleCommand){
                case("1"):
                    System.out.println("1 was selected");
                    String inquiry = ". . list";
                    out.println(inquiry);
                    break;
                case("2"):
                    break;
                case("3"):
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Not a valid command. Please try again.");
                    break;
                }
                if(null != out){
                    out.flush();
                }
                String response = input.readLine();
                System.out.println("Server Response: " + response);
                consoleCommand = myInput.readLine();
            }
            //write the code for disconnect here
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: parseAndSend(commandMessage);
commandMessage = input.readLine();
switch them maybe?

Comment: Wow, I actually figured it out. For some reason addName(sock); function was causing some sort of holdup. Debugging ends up halting at that line in Server.java. I tried moving the function above main, but no luck on that either. Commenting out that function results in a perfect response from the server to the client. I guess now the question becomes why?

Comment: Again, this is what happens when I stay up too long coding. I am waiting on a client to send over a username. It was a function I wrote before everything else, and changed my mind about how that would play out. Can't say it's the first time.

Answer (score -1):

addName(sock); function in Server.java had a input.readline() waiting on the client causing the hang...